# Create http tunnel using connect

Tags: c#, http, https, proxy, tunnel

Good day,
I need to create a tunnel for http requests over a local proxy server. When a Get request comes over http, there are no any problems, however, when it conserns https, we have a Connect request. Here is an example of a browser request to my Proxy server

```
CONNECT google.ru:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: google.ru
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

In case I send this request to Google, I have 0 byte back. Could you tell me what I should do to set a data exchange going?

Comment: You don't send CONNECT requests. You make a socket connection *from your proxy* to the target, then relay the raw data stream back and forth between the two connections.

Comment: Only Sockets? may be TCPClient or other classes

Comment: TCPClient uses sockets. It is a socket connection, no matter what you layer on top of it.

Comment: i do not really introduce looks like a socket that transmits the data stream between the two compounds 
And how should pass the connection between my browser and the server in case of HTTPS?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01